How to move files quickly from wsl2 to windows?
In my WSL2 system, there is a very large folder containing numerous files, and I want to move this folder to my local Windows system. I am currently using the Linux mv command:
sudo mv -fv folder_in_wsl folder_in_windows

However, I find this operation to be too slow and it takes a long time. How can I move the files more quickly?

You could save time to move the files if you used the path to your WSL to access files directly. Type \\wsl$ to access your WSL instance from Windows Explorer. You can use the UNC path directly depending on what you want to do with those files.
